# Non-singularity of a certain block matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

We are given a matrix of the form

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&q_{1}&0&1&0&0\\
    0&2p_{2}q_{2}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&q_{2}&0&0&1&0\\
    0&0&2p_{3}q_{3}&0&0&0&0&0&0&q_{3}&0&0&0&1\\
    0&0&0&2p_{1}q_{1}&0&0&0&0&0&0&q_{1}&1&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&q_{2}&0&1&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&2p_{3}q_{3}&0&0&0&0&q_{3}&0&0&1\\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&2p_{1}q_{1}&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2p_{2}q_{2}&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
    q_{1}&q_{2}&q_{3}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&q_{1}&q_{2}&q_{3}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$

This is an example for $n = 3,$ i.e. it is an $n^2+2n-1$-dimensional matrix,
with all its non-negative entries strictly positive.
We also have that $p_i+q_i = 1,$ and $0 < p_i,q_i.$
I entered this matrix to `maxima` CAS and it successfully finds its determinant. Unfortunately, I could not generalize from there, neither could I get any hypothesis. How to prove this matrix is always non-singular?

EDIT: all the numbers are reals, and the symbols are positive reals.
As to symbolic computations, I have the following `maxima`-targeted 
format:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,q1,0,1,0,0],
[0,2*p2*q2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,q2,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,2*p3*q3,0,0,0,0,0,0,q3,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,2*p1*q1,0,0,0,0,0,0,q1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,q2,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,2*p3*q3,0,0,0,0,q3,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,2*p1*q1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2*p2*q2,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[q1,q2,q3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,q1,q2,q3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

EDIT: For a concrete example of $q_1 = \ldots = q_n = 1/2,$
one would have
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&1&0&0\\
0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&1&0\\\ 0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
{{1}\over{2}}&{{1}\over{2}}&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&{{1}\over{2}}&{{1}\over{2}}&{{1}\over{2}}&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

EDIT: The Wikipedia page says the matrix is positive definite if and only if all its eigenvalues are positive.
I ran `maxima`'s `eigenvalues`-function for the above matrix,
and I got the following:
$$\left[ \left[ \left({{-1}\over{2}}-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}\right)\,
 \left({{\sqrt{469}\,i}\over{4\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{216}}
 \right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}+{{37\,\left({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}+{{-1
 }\over{2}}\right)}\over{36\,\left({{\sqrt{469}\,i}\over{4\,3^{{{3
 }\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{216}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}+{{1}\over{6}}
  , \left({{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}+{{-1}\over{2}}\right)\,\left({{
 \sqrt{469}\,i}\over{4\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{216}}\right)^{
 {{1}\over{3}}}+{{37\,\left({{-1}\over{2}}-{{\sqrt{3}\,i}\over{2}}
 \right)}\over{36\,\left({{\sqrt{469}\,i}\over{4\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}
 +{{1}\over{216}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}+{{1}\over{6}} , \left({{
 \sqrt{469}\,i}\over{4\,3^{{{3}\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{216}}\right)^{
 {{1}\over{3}}}+{{37}\over{36\,\left({{\sqrt{469}\,i}\over{4\,3^{{{3
 }\over{2}}}}}+{{1}\over{216}}\right)^{{{1}\over{3}}}}}+{{1}\over{6}}
  , {{1}\over{2}} \right]  , \left[ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 \right]  \right] $$

Conceptually (if that helps and no-so-obvious from the above representation),
this matrix can be seen as a block matrix $$B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}P&V^{T}\\V&\mathbf{0}\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: you have not said: the matrix is real and symmetric. One way for it to be nonsingular is for it to be positive definite. In turn, one may, at least, attempt to find a nonsingular matrix $P$ so that $P^T H P = D$ is diagonal, where your original matrix is $H.$ It is not necessary to deal with any eigenvalues to do this. I'm afraid I don't have a program to do this with symbols, my program accepts symmetric integer matrices... Oh, right, once you get to $D,$ use Sylvester's Law of Inertia. I think it worth trying your pattern in this way for $n=1$ (if possible) and for $n=2$

Comment: in case of curiosity: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: Then all what is left to do is to show that $D$ is a non-singular matrix, and $P$'s are all non-singular. The $P$s are a product of matrices such as $E+E_{ij},$ where $E_{ij}$ is a all-zero matrix with the cell $(i,j)$ containing $1.$ So, proving that $P$s are non-singular may be possible, but what you refer to by "trying your pattern" possibly means figuring out what exacly -- symbolically -- happens when we apply the "generic" algorithm to my particular case. Short of brushing up my Lisp skills and actually writing a `maxima`-script, I cannot see this with mind's eye only.

Comment: Alright. I would try in specific numbers in order to accomplish anything. If all p,q were set to 1/2, the matrix could be multiplied by an integer (2 ?) to get an integer matrix. Next some of the p set to 1/4, some to 3/4, and so on. If you have the patience, how does the matrix appear for $n=2?$

Comment: This is a saddle point matrix $\begin{bmatrix}M & C^T \\ C & 0\end{bmatrix}$. It will be nonsingular if and only if the kernel of $M$ and the kernel of $C$ only intersect at zero. Such matrices arise as the optimality conditions for constrained quadratic minimization problem $\min_x \frac{1}{2}x^T M x$ such that $Cx=0$. Think of $x^T M x$ as a bowl that may be flat in the directions corresponding to the kernel of $M$, and $Cx=0$ being a hyperplane passing through the origin. There will be a unique minimum if the flat directions in $M$ do not perfectly align with the constraint hyperplane